# How can I extend other chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create extension for extension (for React dev tools). I want to add custom post processing for react components tree rendered by react dev tool.
I tried to use extensions for injecting js code to pages by URL, but it's not working for urls like `chrome-extension://...`
Is there options of how I can implement it?

P.S.
At the moment, the only option that comes to my mind is to keep the page post-processing code on hand, which I can, if necessary, insert into the console open for the page in react dev tools. (but this solution cannot be called convenient)

Comment: Make a copy of that extension and modify it locally, then load as an unpacked extension.

Comment: wOxxOm, Yes, I was just thinking about this. This idea is still not ideal, because... I lose auto-updates of the original extension (which in my case is quite critical). But it’s definitely better than writing code into the console every time